# How can i show virtual button when i click on it like keyboard

Tags: android-layout

We see that when we click on a button on softkeyboard a new button drawn on every buttons like toast, How can i make this for my layout on every buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Place the new button in the same container as the original button
   and make sure that the new button is on top. A RelativeLayout could
   work well.
2. Set the new button's visibility to `INVISIBLE` or `GONE` in `onCreate`.
3. When the user clicks on the original button, change
   the new button's visibility to `VISIBLE` and use a `Handler's`
   `postDelayed` method to hide the new button after a certain amount
   of time.

Comment: please provide an example i am using linear layout, i am new to android

Comment: @VijendraKumarSewaliya give it a shot and ask another question if you run into any issues, but be sure to show what you've tried and what issues you ran into.